# Need SendMessage Command to get List from a VB6 application

Tags: vb6, sendmessage

Hi I have a program that is built using VB6(I do not have the sourcecode, only executable), that has a listbox and will have couple of items in that listbox. I need to read contents of it using SendMessage. Please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if it's a standard or at least documented listbox control. Usually one would use a "spy" program to examine the target app and obtain window titles/classes/etc. used to programmatically locate the window that is the listbox control. Then you just use `SendMessage()` to talk directly to the `HWND` of that control and get the info you need.

See similar question:

[Read listbox content of from another application C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781790/read-listbox-content-of-from-another-application-c-sharp)

Comment: I am using AutoIt to Findout the SendMessage behaviour. It just does not work.